# How to call a javascript function in onTick

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm new to Javascript. I have a div with a scrollbar and I want that when OnTick fires, the scrollbar goes automatically down.

Right now, it works, but only when I send a message (it's a chat) or when I load the conversation (so on the GetMessages of the listview).

**JS**

```
$(function scrollTopYeah() {
    alert('hi');
    document.getElementById('divDuClavardage').scrollTop = 9999999;
});
```

**C#**

```
protected void TimerChat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   lvChat.DataBind();

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "scrollTopYeah();", true);
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myscript", "alert('test')", true);
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myscript2","document.getElementById('divDuClavardage').scrollTop = 99999;", true);
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "scrollTopYeah()", true);
 }
```

I tried all the 4 lines you can see ^... What am I doing wrong? None of them works

I just want to call my JS function onTick!

Thanks,

Comment: If you wanted a JS solution, you can use setInterval to continuously call a function after a specified time period has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are only getting the function to fire when the user sends a message back to the server is because that is the only time the server can send commands to the browser.  The server does not stay connected to the clients browser, it only receives requests and replies to them. So the only time it can notify the clients browser is after the client sends a request to the server, ie sending a message or loading the conversation.

The TimerChat_Tick method is called at some point on the server after the response to the client has returned, and actually is probably not called because it is scoped out after the response returns.

To have the server call something on the client's browser you will need to use websockets or have the timer run within the client side javascript.

While it seems from the name of the method you can just use a setTimeout(function,time) method on the browser.  But if that is not what you are trying to do here is an article on websockets and .net: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-html5-web-sockets-server-with-asp-net-4-5